# Shutting down and restarting virtual machines on VMware as on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

With VMware, when I press the menu buttons for either shutting down or restarting a running virtual machine, the operation is performed using the guest's own power control system. So, if the guest hangs or is in the middle of some process that prevents it from responding to soft shutdown/reboot methods as it would if it were not virtualized, I get "Virtual machine is busy.". On VirtualBox, rebooting or powering down a guest is performed as if I were yanking the power supply from a physical computer. Is there anyway to get VMware to work like that? I am using VMware Workstation Player 12.

Comment: VMware has both, guest->power off and an option to power off the vm itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, Player doesn't offer that choice.

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation provides menu items to perform "hard" power operations and has UI to set whether power operations are "hard" or "soft" by default, but it seems that VMware Player does not provide either ability.

You therefore will need to change your VM's configuration manually, however.  Open the VM's `.vmx` file in a text editor and change `powerType.powerOff` from `"soft"` to `"hard"`. (You may wish to do the same for `powerType.powerOn`, `powerType.suspend`, and `powerType.reset`.) Quit Player and reopen the VM.  When you power it on, the `Player > Power` menu now should show "Power Off" instead of "Shut Down Guest".